# How to convert NUMBER into DATE format

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I need some help. I'm trying to convert PIN (identification number) into date format.

Example: I have PIN 8808067070 I want to take the first 6 characters 880806 and convert them into date format, like this 06.08.1988 /DD.MM.YYYY/

Any ideas how to this?

Comment: With `to_date`, perhaps? What have you done so far? Why would you be able to assume that a PIN starts with six digits that always represent a date?

Answer (score 1):

Use TO_CHAR and an appropriate format:

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR('8808067070',1,6), 'RRmmdd')
```

Comment: what is RR? doesnt it have to be 'YYmmdd'

Comment: `RR` is a specific Oracle format, if a two-digit year is less than 50 it's considered to be in the current century, otherwise it's last century. '14' -> 2014, '88' -> 1988.